# Introducing colour ta a separator

Tags: optional-arguments

I am having difficulty constructing the function `\celest_separ:n` that can handle colour because code level functions do not have optional arguments.  Quite unfortunate.  How may I get out of such problem ?

What is the advantage of using `-` versus `\textemdash` ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\colorlet{celestk}{dblue}

\cs_set_eq:NN \wvAstr \textasteriskcentered
\cs_set_eq:NN \wvDash \textemdash

\cs_new_protected:Nn \celest_separ:n
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
        { \color[#1] }
      { \color[#1]{#2} }

    \begin{center}
      \wvDash \wvDash \wvDash
      \ \wvAstr \, \wvAstr \, \wvAstr
      \ \wvDash \wvDash \wvDash
    \end{center}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \separ {O{celestk}o}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
        { \celest_separ:n [#1] }
      { \celest_separ:n [#1] [#2] }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\separ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Code level functions do not have optional arguments

Comment: Please don't edit to add a new question after your original has been answered. `-` is a hyphen. `\emdash` is a rule which I guess originally, at least, was of length 1em. Em and en are printer's measures. In many cases, `--` and `---` are ligatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call

```
\celest_separ:n [#1]
```

nor

```
\celest_separ:n [#1][#2]
```

You need to absorb the arguments and call internal functions having the correct signature (and definition).

But here I can't see how `expl3` can really help.

You seem to want to allow for calls such as

```
\separ
\separ[red!80]
\separ[rgb][0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

I don't think that the `center` environment is good for the job, actually. And don't overthink about `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\colorlet{celestk}{dblue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\separ}{O{celestk}o}{%
  \par\nopagebreak\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  \noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\color{#1}}{\color[#1]{#2}}%
    ---\!---\!---\ %
    \textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered\,\textasteriskcentered
    \ ---\!---\!---%
  }\par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\separ

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\separ[red!80]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\separ[rgb][0.4,0.1,0.1]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\end{document}
```

Here `twocolumn` is used just to get a smaller picture.

[image]